# What is the "good conscience" mentioned in 1 Timothy 1:5,19

Tags: greek, word-study, pauline-epistles, 1-timothy, conscience

1. What is the **"good conscience"** mentioned in 1 Timothy 1:5,19 ?

> 1 Timothy 1:5 Now the end of the commandment is charity out of a pure
>   heart, and of a **good conscience**, and of faith unfeigned:
>
> 1 Timothy 1:19 Holding faith, and a **good conscience**; which some having
>   put away concerning faith have made shipwreck:

2. What is the opposite of a good conscience?
3. How to get a good conscience?
4. How can we lose a good conscience?
5. What are the dangers of not having a good conscience?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.studylight.org/commentary/1-timothy/1-5.html

> Albert Barnes' Notes on the Whole Bible
>
> And of a good conscience - A conscience free from guilt. Of course
>   there can be no genuine love to God where the dictates of conscience
>   are constantly violated, or where a man knows that he is continually
>   doing wrong. If a man wishes to have the evidence of love to God, he
>   must keep a good conscience. All pretended love, where a man knows
>   that he is living in sin, is mere hypocrisy.

https://www.studylight.org/commentary/1-timothy/1-19.html

> Commentary Critical and Explanatory on the Whole Bible
>
> Holding — Keeping hold of “faith” and “good conscience” (1 Timothy
>   1:5); not “putting the latter away” as “some.” Faith is like a very
>   precious liquor; a good conscience is the clean, pure glass that
>   contains it [Bengel]. The loss of good conscience entails the
>   shipwreck of faith. Consciousness of sin (unrepented of and forgiven)
>   kills the germ of faith in man [Wiesinger].
>
> which — Greek singular, namely, “good conscience,” not “faith” also;
>   however, the result of putting away good conscience is, one loses
>   faith also.
>
> put away — a willful act. They thrust it from them as a troublesome
>   monitor. It reluctantly withdraws, extruded by force, when its owner
>   is tired of its importunity, and is resolved to retain his sin at the
>   cost of losing it. One cannot be on friendly terms with it and with
>   sin at one and the same time.
>
> made shipwreck — “with respect to THE faith.” Faith is the vessel in
>   which they had professedly embarked, of which “good conscience” is the
>   anchor. The ancient Church often used this image, comparing the course
>   of faith to navigation. The Greek does not imply that one having once
>   had faith makes shipwreck of it, but that they who put away good
>   conscience “make shipwreck with respect to THE faith.”